# Xamarin DependencyService with Parameterized Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

How I can use Xamarin Forms DependencyService  to inject dependency through Parameterized Constructor ?

Comment: Can you please post the complete question. Include how you are calling Dependency Service to resolve your implementations or something you are getting exceptions on.

Comment: DependencyService only works with default constructors.  If you need something more complicated you will need to use a different DI Container

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Answer

You cannot.

The assembly attribute implementation only works with default constructors (aka parameterless constructors), e.g.`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyClass))]`.

The run-time implementation also only works with default constructors (aka parameterless constructors), e.g `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<T>()`

**Edit**: (Highlighting [Nitha Paul's question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586251/xamarin-dependencyservice-with-parameterized-constructor/56586722?noredirect=1#comment99751758_56586722)): `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService` is a [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), not an [IoC Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin), and Service Locators cannot do Dependency Injection.

### Recommendation

I recommend using [TinyIoC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyIoC/) for your Dependency Injection.

Here are performance metrics showing TinyIoC is the fastest IoC tool for Xamarin.Forms: https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-perf-playground#ioc

```
public class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // Register DI
        TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<INumber>(new NumberClass(42));
        TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<MyClass>();

        // Resolve DI
        var myClass = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<MyClass>();
        Console.Writeline(myClass.ToString()); //42

    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    readonly INumber _number;

    public int MyClass(INumber number)
    {
         _number = number;
    }

    public override ToString() => _number.Num;
}

public class NumberClass : INumber
{
    public NumberClass(int number)
    {
        Num = number;
    }

    public int Num { get; }
}

public interface INumber
{
    int Num { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to mix both IOC containers together in app. In my app I am already build so many features. So changing the current implementation can be a difficult task. I am wondering about using simple ioc, when ever required something like that?

Comment: yepp, you can mix an IOC container with the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService. I already do it in my apps with Prism and Dryloc

Comment: It sounds like there are two questions here, so I'll try to answer both: 1. Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService is not an IoC container, it is a Service Locator; 2. I recommend using one IoC container in an application. If you're already using Simple IoC, definitely continue using it. This answer just shows an example using TinyIoc, but if you prefer a different IoC container, like SimpleIoC, fo for it! I would not recommend using both TinyIoC and SimpleIoC together in the same app.

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba  Could you please share some sample or describe the way you are using it?

Comment: @Brandon Minnick : Can you share some sample?

Comment: @NithaPaul The answer above has an example of how to use TinyIoC