# How to implement Constructor injection into Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I would like to create a Xamarin app that makes use of the dependency injection pattern. My current problem is that I just cannot get it to work with xamarin in any other way than as a dependency locator anti-pattern, while I want an actual constructor injection. I have tried everything I could find, from Prism templates to tinyIoC, but the ViewModels and Views simply require a parameterless constructor. What am I missing?

The following are some sources that were helpful but did not resolve my issue

- [Xamarin DependencyService with Parameterized Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586251/xamarin-dependencyservice-with-parameterized-constructor)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection
- https://github.com/windows-toolkit/MVVM-Samples

My app is a fresh xamarin forms template generated by VS2019, I only added a few libraries but those should not interfere in any way. Xamarin clearly provides a built-in dependency locator, but that is not what I wanted to use. I also saw a few templates that achieved what I wanted, but they were too big for me to find out how exactly they achieved that.

Ideally, I would like to use Microsoft MVVM Toolkit, but that is not a strict requirement. I would also like the implementation to be as simple as possible, as I am just starting with xamarin development.

An example of what I would like to achieve:

```
public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AboutViewModel(ITest testService)
        {
            Title = "About";
            OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart"));
        }

        public ICommand OpenWebCommand { get; }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        void Test();
    }

    class TestService : ITest
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test successful");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out I had this in my AboutPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:AboutViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Seems like a simple way to initialize viewModel in view except it can only accept parameterless constructors. That is what was causing my problems. Moving the ViewModel initialization into the code behind solved everything, though I would still prefer to just pass it through codebehind constructor.
This is the result now:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<AboutViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: FWIW: Now that you have removed the parameterless xaml that was causing the problem. why can't you pass it in as a parameter? Your question code snippet shows only a ViewModel. Your answer shows only a View. I can't tell from your question what you wanted to do, and I can't tell from your "answer" how that solved your problem. As it stands, this Q&A won't be useful to anyone else. It would be great if you added more code to both question and answer, to show what the problem was, and a complete solution for it!

Comment: Its also not clear to me why you are taking an already complex model, MVVM, and adding another layer of complexity, by doing dependency injection. Practice incremental development with refactoring. Find the simplest possible code that does what you need today. Not the most flexible code - that almost always adds a layer of indirection or abstraction that will slow down development. The simplest dumbest code that will work for current objectives. `AboutPage(AboutViewModel vm) { InitializeComponent(); BindingContext = vm;}`.  Usage: `new AboutPage(new AboutviewModel(testService));`  Done.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I currently cannot just inject the AboutVIewModel into AboutPage because of the way the constructor is called. The default template seems to just call it directly and I will have to fix that first or it would cause the same problem all over again, just one step higher. Maybe once I have everything up and running like I want to I will show how I did that here, but RN I am afraid I would cause more problems if I started editing the question.

Comment: ok, np.  Most valuable is showing a oompete solution in your answer. Would be great to see exactly what is going on. What "default template" are you referring to?  The three lines of XAML at top of your answer?  But you've removed those now, right? Is there similar XAML elsewhere, that it isn't easy to remove?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve In visual studio Xamarin extension has a default template built in.  If you generate that you will get the exact same thing as me.

Comment: OK. But you have to manually edit anyway, to add your line of code to the constructor. So if you delete those three lines of XAML you found, then you can do whatever you want. Edit in the parameter you'd like to have. Any reason not to?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You see, the AboutPage codebehind itself needs to have a default constructor in this template too. Even though it is not constrained by xaml, the way it is called by navigation does not support DI out of the box as far as I know. Give it a try and see for yourself, maybe you will have more luck than I did.